# Boot device not found hard disk (3F0) HP with Debian 10

Tags: hard-drive, boot, debian, grub, grub2

I have an HP Pavilion power 15-cb030nl with Debian 10 buster installed.

Several months ago I changed the SSD with a larger one, cloning the entire system (there was debian 9 on it) using clonezilla.

This morning I connected the old SSD (the one with debian 9 installed) via USB using an external adapter. Switch on the laptop, and the following error appeared:

```
Boot Device Not Found
Please install an operating system on your hard disk
Error codes:
Hard Disk - (3F0)
F2 System diagnostics
```

Even if removing the external ssd, the black screen keeps showing up.

I tough that for some reason grub files were missing or corrupted, so I tried a Ubuntu live USB version and re-installed grub (via chroot on my debian), so grub appears, but it is empty!

Please notice that I can read the ssd with debian 10 from ubuntu live, so I don't think that the ssd is corrupted or physically not well connected.

this is what I see from *fdisk -l*

```
    Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 2027323392 bytes, 3959616 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop1: 89.3 MiB, 93581312 bytes, 182776 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop2: 53.7 MiB, 56315904 bytes, 109992 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop3: 151 MiB, 158343168 bytes, 309264 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop4: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop5: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop6: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop7: 3.7 MiB, 3821568 bytes, 7464 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
    Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB               
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 9484CCFA-0E07-4985-848D-56A9404D460F

    Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
    /dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   6049666   4999043   2.4G Linux filesystem
    /dev/nvme0n1p3 6049667 976773134 970723468 462.9G Linux LVM


    Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
    Disk model: ST1000LM049-2GH1
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 34F9309F-9994-49CA-93BE-1BCF2C285E39

    Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sda1        2048 1919397887 1919395840 915.2G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda2  1919397888 1953523711   34125824  16.3G Microsoft basic data


    Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7736072192 bytes, 15109516 sectors
    Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x46f8e7bf

    Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
    /dev/sdb1  *          0 4095999 4096000    2G  0 Empty
    /dev/sdb2       4066772 4074259    7488  3.7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


    Disk /dev/mapper/naptor--vg-root: 447 GiB, 479945818112 bytes, 937394176 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/mapper/naptor--vg-swap_1: 15.9 GiB, 17062428672 bytes, 33325056 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/loop8: 35.3 MiB, 37027840 bytes, 72320 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

As you can see, the ssd that is giving me problems is: */dev/nvme0n1*

Another thing that I tried is to use Super grub to restore grub, but the weird thing is that it doesn't *see* the operating system either. This is a screenshot of what I got from super grub live:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/460FI.jpg  [Please see the image, i can't post it here since I don't have enough reputation]

I tried *Boot repair* but it gets stuck when trying to reinstall grub.
This is the boot-repair info log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nnFNJ3pKTK/

I also enabled Legacy Support in BIOS (instead of using UEFI) but it's completely the same.

Actually I don't know if the external ssd broke everything, or something else happened (maybe an update in debian? don't think so..).

However it seems to me that it's not related to grub at this point, but I really have no more ideas.

EDIT:
*efibootmgr -v*

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,0001,3001,0000,2002,2004
Boot0000* EFI Hard Drive (Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-25-38-5B-81-B0-FE-44)/HD(1,GPT,ace2a167-78a7-4446-95bc-efc429f8383c,0x800,0x100000)RC
Boot0001* grub  HD(1,GPT,ace2a167-78a7-4446-95bc-efc429f8383c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\grub\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - KingstonDataTraveler 3.0 (KingstonDataTraveler 3.0)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(16,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x46f8e7bf,0x3e0dd4,0x1d40)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

Comment: If the problem appeared with UEFI boot, it could be you happen to screw your EFI System Partition. HP has "efi file run" in their bios setup, from which you can browse ESP and run any file from it. Try to run grub that way. Also, Debian 10 brings Secure Boot support via shim loader, so firmware doesn't call for grub directly. To have more help, boot live cd in UEFI mode and show efibootmgr -v.

Comment: I tried to run "efi file" but nothing changes. grub still saying only "system setup" and if I click on it, I hear a beep and the pc restarts. I also tried legacy support and disabled secure boot in the bios with no luck. I added efibootmgr -v output in the question.

Comment: See, it is strange, currently boot is "0002", probably this is your resque. First in "normal" boot sequence is 2001. What is that 2001? Why USB device is there? I suspect correct one is 0001 (shimx64.efi, which is supposed to run grub next to it). I'll remove it with 'efibootmgr -o 0001" (setting boot order to 0001 and nothing else). Next to check is if there is really grub next to it, grub.cfg file, kernel and initramfs where grub looks for them.

Comment: 0002 is the ubuntu live usb, that's why it's current boot I guess. 2001 have no idea of what it is and maybe the correct one could be 0001 or 0000 (this is the ssd with debian installed)

Comment: (sorry, I sent early by mistake, then edited)

Comment: so you suggest to set boot order to 0001 and not 0000? can I restore it later in case it doesn't work? will I be able to start the live usb again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98982/discussion-between-nikita-kipriyanov-and-myh34d).